# Fundamental groups of homotopy equivalent spaces

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

[image]

In the above proof I don't know how you can say that there exists such a function $g$. Can someone explain this to me? thank you!

Comment: This $g$ exists by the definition of homotopy equivalence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $f$ is a homotopy equivalence, then by definition such a $g$ exists.

Comment: Thanks! So in other words, $f$ is a homeomorphism right?

Comment: Not at all, $f$ needs not to be a homeomorphism! When writting $f\circ g\simeq\textrm{id}_Y$, one means that $f\circ g$ is *homotopic* to $\textrm{id}_Y$, namely there exists $H:Y\times[0,1]\rightarrow Y$ continuous such that $H(\cdot,0)=f\circ g$ and $H(\cdot,1)=\textrm{id}_Y$, $H$ may not be constant.